# Cleaning white bubbles on induction stove

Tags: cleaning, stove, induction

I recently moved into an apartment with an induction stove. After the first use with a designated pan, some white bubble marks have appeared. Has anyone had these types of stains? Any suggestions on how to clean it?

[image: White marks on stove top]

Comment: I can't recognize the material of the stove surface. (It is not dependent on the fact that it is induction, I have even used a bare-coil design). Is it glass? Also, can it just be dried out spilled hard water?

Comment: Have you tried doing anything at all?
On my ceramic top stove, I use a scraper to remove residue, along with a commercial-grade stove cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

I have an induction stove and have had similar marks. I think rumtscho is right; these are mineral deposits from water. Water gets between the surface and the pan, most likely because the base of the pan was initially wet (spillage from the pan will mostly end up beside it, and only areas directly under the pan will get significantly hot), the heat of the pan evaporates the water, leaving dry deposits.

There is some [good advice on cleaning glass stovetops from eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_12087900_hardwater-stains-off-flattop-stove.html), which suggests leaving a "[vinegar-drenched] paper towel on the stove top for an hour", and using ceramic cooktop cleaner if still present.

But I've found these marks can be mostly prevented by making sure the base of your pan is completely dry before putting it on the stove.

Answer (score 1):

We bought/installed a new Samsung glass top stove today. After the first time of using the top, it looked like little bubbles arose on the burner in wich I used.

I thought maybe a protective film was there. Couldn't find one... I also didn't understand how there could be one as I used the eye for 20 mins with no other sign of a film melting or anything like that. It looked like the bubbles appeared from under the surface.

I started reading posts on this and other websites.

I had just washed,and patted dry, the frying pan I used. I read it could be mineral bubbles from using a wet pan when begaining to cook. I also read on the Samsung website it is not a default in the stove top.. to use some "elbow grease" (I am paraphrasing) and the spots will come up. I didn't have a 000 steal wool pad so I used the backside of a sponge (the scratchy side..but it wasn't very abrasive..) and rubbed in tiny circles OVER and OVER with a tiny bit of dawn dish soap. The bubbles disappeared.

This is my first time dealing with this. I don't know if it is because we use well water.. or if a wet pan caused it. I don't know if it was my elbow grease, so to speak, that helped remove the spots... but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After using my new glass-topped stove to do a chicken stir fry.  Used the suggested cleaner closely following directions.  Allow to cool totally shake and spray cleaner - use special pad and wipe clean and buff with clean paper towel.  There were raised prickly bubbles all around he rim of the burner and streaky marks across the center of the burner I was sick.  I researched and tried each suggestion with the least abrasive first.  FINALLY I used my old stand by BonAmi cleaner made into a paste and rubbed aggressively with the special pad.  Wipe with damp paper towel and then I sprayed the area with Windex White Vinegar cleaner and wiped with special microfiber glass cloth.  Perfect - like new.  However I will note - it took me 20 minutes to do the entire stir-fry dinner and over an hour and a half to clean the stove.  If I had it to do over - I'd go coil.

Comment: Is there still a protective plastic film on the stove, which you melted in spots?

Answer (score -1):

You have a couple of options.

Grade 000 steel wool. I was put onto it by a builder when I was cleaning very dirty windows, we pretty much use it on everything, when its not rusty (throw away when it is) its virtually scratch free for all surfaces but removes tough built on dirt, sopa scum, fades hard water marks and eventually removes them.

You can try a scrapper but you would have to be cautious not to scratch it as this is a possibility. You can also try a product like "Bring it on cleaner" we have used this product and can vouch it is what it says it is. Unfortunately is is pretty costly. Another option is cerium oxide. I wouldn't recommend this option unless you have worked with it before.

Comment: promotion in posts, for your or others' blogs or sites, is allowed as long as it is pointing to a page which contains a direct answer to the question. Your links weren't, so I removed them.